# Как на JS разместить числа из одномерного массива в двумерный парами?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеется массив с числами. Например:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
```

Как разместить их попарно в двумерном массиве, чтобы получился такой двумерный массив:

```
let arr2 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]];
```

Comment: а циклом не пытался?

Comment: Можно циклом по массиву первому и число по индексу парному, как во втором массиве 0,0 0,1 0,2 ... 0,n а непарные как 1,0 1,1 1,2 ... 1,n

Comment: А что должно получиться, если в исходном массиве нечетное количество элементов?

Comment: @Yaant 0 например

Comment: В английской версии SO есть хорошее универсальное решение - [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8495740/3446071)

Answer (score 3):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
let arr2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  if (arr[i] != undefined && arr[i+1] != undefined) {
    arr2.push([ arr[i], arr[i+1] ]);
  }
}
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: Ну вот как я и говорил. Знаете то чувство, когда язык знаешь поверносно но знаешь другой неплохо которые похожи. Способ знаешь а реализовать не смог. Это я пытался ответ написать))

Comment: Спасибо огромное!))) Два часа голову над циклом ломал. А все очень просто оказалось.

Answer (score 2):

Если понадобиться разбить массив на другое кол-во элементов, а не только по два:

```js
const chunkArray = (arr, cnt) => arr.reduce((prev, cur, i, a) => !(i % cnt) ? prev.concat([a.slice(i, i + cnt)]) : prev, []);

let sourceArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

console.log(chunkArray(sourceArr, 2));
console.log(chunkArray(sourceArr, 3));
console.log(chunkArray(sourceArr, 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Перебираем ключи. Встретили чётный? - Создали новый вложенный массив для очередной пачки. В любом случае пишем очередной элемент в нужную пачку, а индекс определяем округлением вниз отношения ключа к двум. Немношк гольферских хаков сократят размер кода до:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
let arr2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    !(i % 2) && arr2.push([]);
    arr2[i / 2 << 0].push(arr[i]);
}
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: Сократят размер кода, но увеличат количество проходов цикла.

Comment: @Anamnian "Преждевременная оптимизация есть корень всех зол" (С) Tony Hoare

Comment: Причем здесь это? В вашем случае количество проходов по циклу соответствует количеству элементов в массиве, если будет 1 миллион элементов- цикл запустится миллион раз.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function convertArr(arr, cols) { // cols - указывает на количество элементов в подмассиве
    let resultArr = [];

    // будем пушить и резать массив, пока не опустошим его полностью
    while(arr.length > 0) { 
        resultArr.push(arr.slice(0, cols)); // пушим первые элементы исходного массива в новый
        arr.splice(0, cols) // удаляем запушенные элементы из исходного массива
    }
    // вернем новый массив
    return resultArr;
}
// проверим:
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
let cols = 2;

console.log(convertArr(arr, cols));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]